# How do we run Liquibase reliably over an unreliable network connection?

Tags: jdbc, liquibase

When running our Liquibase migrations using the command line `liquibase` tool, we occasionally get `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException`s due to reset connections. Unfortunately we have an unreliable network between our application and our database.

We've been able to work around this in our application code by implementing a retry mechanism if we get a recoverable exception (although not ideal, it does work). We don't seem to have this level of control in Liquibase.

Has anyone been able to work around this or a similar problem?

Comment: Just an idea and maybe one possible solution: Instead of running liquibase command `update` run `updateSQL` and generate an SQL file that contains alle the SQLs that liquibase normally runs. Send the file to someone who can run this directly on the db (without the unreliable connection in between). Just an idea....

Comment: Or instead of sending this file it is possible to apply it using simple jdbc program with retry logic.